# JavaScript code executed from a JSF Managed Bean not working

Tags: javascript, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

The following **JavaScript** code executed in this **JSF Managed Bean**'s logout method does not work, though the java code actually does. So, though the log-out actually occurs, the JavaScript code (which basically click on a button) is not executed. Any ideas of what may be happening ? Thanks is advance !

```
@SessionScoped
@ManagedBean(name = "LoginController")
public class LoginController implements Serializable {
...
public void logout() {
        try {

            RequestContext rc = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();

            script = "$('#btnLogOut').prop('disabled', false); window.location.reload(true); $('#btnLogOut').click(); $('#btnLogOut').prop('disabled', true);";
            rc.execute(script);

            ExternalContext ec = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
            ec.invalidateSession();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("error", e);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Sounds too unclear... Maybe you can give us a little information about JS-errors from your web-console?

Comment: Hi Dmitry, thanks, but I do not have much more details because I am running JSF/PrimeFaces over JavaFX, so I do not have access to Chrome's console. I installed Firebug Lite in JavaFX, but it's not of much help either. It does not show any errors (at least I do not see them).

Comment: Most likely the javascript code doesn't work becuz you invalidate the session.

Answer (score 1):

You reload the page with `window.location.reload(true);` at the beginning of the script, so the browser may not have time to execute the part which goes after it, where the logout button is clicked.

Comment: **Hi sainaen !** thanks, I will try your suggestion.